# Using try-with-resources statement with JDBC4.0 and previous

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Directly from [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html) oracle tutorial:

> In JDBC 4.1, which is available in Java SE release 7 and later, you
>   can use a try-with-resources statement to automatically close

Does it mean that if I use Java 7 with JDBC 4.0 or previous versions I won't be able to use the try-with-resources statement?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using try-with-resource in Java 7 with a JDBC 4.0 (or earlier) driver will work. Your application uses the `java.sql` interfaces from Java 7, and it is these interfaces that implement `java.lang.AutoCloseable`. The JDBC 4.0 implementation will have a `close()` method that conforms to the `AutoCloseable` contract (that is it has a method `close()` and it throws a subclass of `Exception`), so it will work.

The fact that it wasn't compiled against that 'version' of the interface doesn't matter, it is the runtime combination of interfaces and implementation that decides that it works. This is a result of the [linking of classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.3) and  the [Binary Compatibility](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-13.html) defined in the Java Language Specification.